# Grafana http metrics - remove just one exception coming from a uri

Tags: prometheus, grafana, spring-boot-actuator, promql, grafana-alerts

I am using this promql expr for grafana alerts from my spring boot application.

```yaml
expr: 'sum(increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count{app="galacsvc", status=~"4.*"}[1m])) by (uri) > 100'
```

I would like to silence an exception from a certain URI, so I tried the following:

```yaml
expr: 'sum(increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception!="GrumIsNotActive", uri!="/v1/grum/execute", app="galacsvc", status=~"4.*"}[1m])) by (uri) > 100'
```

Now this will silence all other exceptions from uri `/v1/grum/execute` and will also silence the exception `GrumIsNotActive` from all other `uri`.

I searched promql docs, and came across its binary operator `and`. I tried something like

```yaml
expr: 'sum(increase(http_server_requests_seconds_count{(exception!="GrumIsNotActive" and uri!="/v1/grum/execute"), app="galacsvc", status=~"4.*"}[1m])) by (uri) > 100'
```

But above promql is just invalid.
How do I write `expr` to silence an exception coming from a particular uri?

Answer (score 0):

You need `unless` operator for filtering out unneeded time series - see [docs for unless operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators).

The following query must properly exclude time series with simultaneusly set labels for `exception="GrumIsNotActive"` and `uri="/v1/grum/execute"` from the returned sum:

```
sum(
  increase(
http_server_requests_seconds_count{app="galacsvc",status=~"4.*"}[1m])
  unless
http_server_requests_seconds_count{exception="GrumIsNotActive",uri="/v1/grum/execute"}
) by (uri) > 100
```